# How to align only a part of multiple objects to one point?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, selections

I want some arrows point to one specific point.

Like this:

[image]

How can I make it so the arrows point in one direction?

I tried selecting every arrowhead with the direct selection tool, then via shift an anchor point to which I want to align (created as a temporary object) and then specified the distance in the align menu.

But it doesn't want to look as smooth and equal as on the picture. How I can align my selection more regularly?

UPDATE:

For a better clarification I uploaded an image which shows only the arrows like they should be. The rectangles are not part of my image. Therefore ignore the rectangles more or less and take this image as reference:

[image]

Comment: you can get some idea from this post and a duplicate http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30043/automatically-move-its-associated-objects-when-move-one-object/30046#30046

Comment: It is not advised to change the questions after you get answer related to the first version - the answers loose the connection with the edited question, thus it looks like not solving any issue.

Comment: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/985/would-you-like-to-add-the-word-edition-to-the-edited-questions

Comment: better now? I reverted the changes and added them as "UPDATE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give a "general" answer, play with the options to find a variant you like.

Let's say we have this object (if you have multiple ones - UNITE them):

[image]

We choose the operation from Effect menu -

[image]

Now, appears this popup menu -

[image]

We drag upper anchor points as we wish -

[image]

Press OK, and we've done:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

But my arrows are not united with the rectangle beneath them and I want to only let the arrows point and the rectangle not to change. Imagine my picture without the rectangle they "sitting" on.

Comment: @philmcole Please,inform us if this helped - other user will glad to know the answer provide some solution to the problem.

Comment: now, it looks ok to me. I'd advise to create a 2 rectangles , unite all the parts with one of them and after free transformation via pathfinder cut off the rectangle - you will get original grouped parts...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution. What Ilan suggested worked for me, but I found it not so easy and simple.

My steps:

1. select all your lines you want to point to one point (in my case this are the arrows) with the Selection Tool and by holding SHIFT
2. Object -> Expand...
3. Object -> Expand appearance
4. Effect -> Distort & Transform -> Free Distort...
5. in the popup menu take the upper right and left ankerpoints and drag them as far to the middle as you want.

What I fount quite difficult was to get both ankerpoints equal to the middle. I really had to count every dash of the dashed line to get them equal...
There is also the free-transform-tool (Shortcut E), with which I could easily let them point to one point, but the perspective doesn't change accordingly (looks more 2D-like). So I went with the suggestion from Ilan.